# Is it possible for mechanical waves to somehow affect an electromagnetic wave travelling in the same medium?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation

By the word "affecting" I mean cases like increasing or decreasing the opponent's speed. My teacher told me that it is not possible. But he couldn't elaborate or give a clear explanation. As I don't have clear knowledge about this, I wonder why it is impossible. I think that mechanical waves can reduce the speed of an electromagnetic wave after hitting it.

Comment: Check out https://wp.optics.arizona.edu/milster/wp-content/uploads/sites/48/2016/06/acousto-optics-modulator.pdf

Comment: mechanical waves can compress material, which will (probably) change it's refractive index, which will slow down the electromagnetic wave *in the material*

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See related question:
[Light propagating through a sound wave](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/466916/)

Comment: What do you mean by "opponent"?  Do you mean can the mechanical wave decrease the speed of the electromagnetic wave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the question is not same , but reading all the answers of this question you will definitely get the answer

[Is there any effect on mechanical waves by electromagnetic waves (and vise versa)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/264441/252460)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Two examples are 1) surface acoustic wave devices (or *SAW devices*) and 2) *quartz crystal filters*. In both cases, transmission of electric current through the device establishes (very tiny) mechanical movement in the device, which locally alters its electrical properties, which alters the mechanical movements, etc., etc.

Answer (score 1):

The polariton is the coupling of an electromagnetic wave in a material with a electric or magnetic field carrying excitation in the material:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polariton

A subclass of those that directly relates to your question is the phonon polariton, which is coupling of the electromagnetic wave to the physical high-frequency mechanical oscillation of atoms in the material.